# Mysql não guarda configuração

Tags: mysql, wamp

Bom dia.
Utilizo o MySQL versão 5.5.20 em servidor WAMP.

Tenho uma instrução SQL que precisa de um pouco mais de memória do que vem definido por default, para retornar os dados.

Então eu aumentei o valor do `max_allowed_packet` para o tamanho que necessito no `my.ini`, e reinicio os serviços.

Faço esse `select` para confirmar as informações salvas: `Select @@global.max_allowed_packet`, tudo certo.

Mas no outro dia as configurações voltam ao que eram anteriormente.

Já passaram por isso ou podem me dar uma ideia de como resolver.

Obs.: Já tentei setar o valor global desse modo: `set global max_allowed_packet = valor`, mas acontece o mesmo supracitado.

Muito obrigado.

Comment: Você precisa editar o my.ini toda vez apôs reiniciar sua máquina? Caso sim, você não tem nenhum Freeze configurado?

Comment: Não, nenhum.
Eu edito o my.ini e acontece o que disse no lá em cima.

Comment: Você disse `"Mas no outro dia as configurações voltam ao que eram anteriormente."` isso só acontece realmente após 24 horas, ou é após uma reinicialização do SO?

Comment: Após 24 horas, não foi reiniciado o servidor nem os serviços do MYSQL.